# Square Connect API List Payments Endpoint not showing 'Description'

Tags: square-connect

In the example response for the List Payments endpoint in the [Square Connect API Documentation](https://connect.squareup.com/docs/api#get-payments), it shows 'Description' as a returned key, but the data I am receiving from Square does not show that key.

I have verified that the payments do have a Description attached to them (by downloading the transaction report from the Square Dashboard).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for identifying this inconsistency between the documentation and the API. The [`Payment`](https://connect.squareup.com/docs/api?path=connect#datatype-payment) object does *not* in fact have a `description` field.

However, the following fields included in a `Payment` object *do* contain merchant-specified notes about a payment (assuming the merchant provided them at the time of sale):

- The `payment_note` field of a `Payment`’s `tender` contains a merchant-specified note about the form of tender used for the payment. This is generally present only for [`Tender`](https://connect.squareup.com/docs/api?path=connect#datatype-tender) objects with a type of `OTHER`.
- The `notes` field of a [`PaymentItemization`](https://connect.squareup.com/docs/api?path=connect#datatype-paymentitemization) in a `Payment` contains a merchant-specified note about that particular item in the payment. Note that `PaymentItemization`s are only available from the [Retrieve Payment](https://connect.squareup.com/docs/api?path=connect#get-paymentid) endpoint (not [List Payments](https://connect.squareup.com/docs/api?path=connect#get-payments)).

The **Description** column of the transaction report provided by the merchant dashboard is simply a comma-separated list of the names of the items included in the payment, along with any `notes` for each item. The Connect API does not provide this list directly, but you can recreate it for a payment with the fields of the payment’s `itemizations`.